# One test for multiple data in BDD-style testing using Catch

Tags: c++, testing, bdd

I am using C++ and Catch framework for testing. What is the proper way to write a test case in BDD-style using Catch when a set of criteria should be met on multiple data without code duplication?

As an example, assume this test scenario:

```
SCENARIO( "Test the graph deserialization" ) {
    GIVEN( "A graph" ) {
        Graph g;
        WHEN( "It is loaded by file name" ) {
            g.load( "small_graph.gf" );
            THEN( "It has correct number of nodes and edges" ) {
                REQUIRE( g.node_count() == 210 );
                REQUIRE( g.edge_count() == 306 );
            }
        }
        WHEN( "It is loaded by input stream" ) {
            std::ifstream ifs( "small_graph.gf" );
            g.load( ifs );
            THEN( "It has correct number of nodes and edges" ) {
                REQUIRE( g.node_count() == 210 );
                REQUIRE( g.edge_count() == 306 );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As it can be seen, the `THEN` blocks are redundant. What is the proper way to do the same without writing the same code again.

Answer (score 1):

I would extract a method and call it whenever I need instead of duplicating the functionality.